# Is it logical that Unity 5, when adding terrian, the CPU is getting to 100%?

Tags: unity-game-engine

From what I've read the unity terrian is working to calculate and working on lights shades texture not really sure since event before I make anything with the terrain it's starting to work and the CPU is getting high to 100%.

I found that if I uncheck in the inspector the terrain to be NOT static then the CPU is normal. The question is how important is the static and this working on the terrain? Maybe I can make it not static work on the terrain and the game and only in the end to make it static and let it work?

Every change I make in the terrain when the terrain is static it start to work over again and make the CPU usage 100% and everything slow.

[image: Static]

[image: 100% cpu usage]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get up to 100% on my Computer.
What i realize is that some programs like Photoshop use more CPU usage, when RAM is full.

And what is the plane for?
If you want prevent the player from falling off the map,
you can do a simple line into a Update void.

```
int fallOffY = -20;
Vector3 respawnPosition = new Vector3(0,10, 0);
void Update(){
    if(player.position.y<fallOffY){
        player.position = respawnPosition;
    }
}
```

Also it could be, that if you don't use a graphic card, your CPU do the job as a graphic card too.

You Plane is really big.

Edit: try to turn off bakeing.

Edit: Google-ing gave me this:

> What I would do is Uncheck "Auto" and Other Lighting Options. This was the only way for me :/

Comment: Technically, it could also happen if you use a GPU. There are problems associated with modifying data the GPU is using that can cause the driver in D3D/GL to make the CPU wait. If it's a busy-wait, then CPU will reach 100% despite doing no actual work.